# Adjust height UITableViewCell after cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: objective-c, dynamic, uitableview, height

I can't set the height of my `UITableViewCell` according to my constrains.

I have in each cell on my `UITableView` a `UILabel` where the height is not fixed and depends of the height of this `UILabel`.

I tried to set the frame on the cell after I update the label's content but nothing happens. Please find my code below:

```
//On my controller
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CommentCell";

    CommentCell *commentCell = [tView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (commentCell == nil) {
        commentCell = [[CommentCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    Comment *comment;
    if (commentsArray.count > indexPath.row) {
        comment = [commentsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    [commentCell setComment:comment];
    [commentCell setCommonFields];
    currentCellheight = commentCell.contentLabel.frame.size.height + 40;
    DDLogInfo(@"Current Cell Height: %f", currentCellheight);
    return commentCell;
}

//On my custom Cell (CommentCell.m)
-(void)setCommonFields {
    if (self.comment != nil) {
        self.contentLabel.text = self.comment.content;
        self.contentLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(self.contentLabel.frame.size.width, FLT_MAX);
        CGRect expectedLabelRect = [self.contentLabel.text boundingRectWithSize:maximumLabelSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:nil context:nil];
        CGRect newFrame = self.contentLabel.frame;
        newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelRect.size.height;
        self.contentLabel.frame = newFrame;

    }
}
```

I tried also to set the height thanks to the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method but this method is called **before** `cellForRowAtIndexPath` where my label is updated.

I don't have much more idea to solve this problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: No magic, you need to determine your height in the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method and return it. You cannot set the height of the cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Rohit's answer, please find my working code:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSString *content=((Comment *)[commentsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]).content;
    CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(234.00f, FLT_MAX);
    CGRect expectedLabelRect = [content boundingRectWithSize:maximumLabelSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:nil context:nil];

    if (expectedLabelRect.size.height > 41) {
        return expectedLabelRect.size.height + 81;
    }
    else
        return 81;
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend against using hard-coded values like `234.00f`. Especially now that we have the iPhone 6/6 Plus (but even when this was answered, we had iPad screens), this will likely yield unintended effects. If you're going to hard-code values like this, it's much better to do so in the `UITableViewCell` subclass where you can use different hard-coded values for different devices.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{


                NSLog(@"indexPath.row :%ld",(long)indexPath.row);

                CGSize contsize={260.00f,3000.00f};
                UIFont *font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:15.0];

                NSString *strt11=@"hellllllooooooooooooooooooo  hellllllooooooooooooooooooo  hellllllooooooooooooooooooo";

                CGSize fontSize=[strt11 sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:contsize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

                NSLog(@"fontSize indexPath :%f",fontSize.height);

                if (fontSize.height>22)
                    return fontSize.height+50.0f;

           }




    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {


            UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"reuse"];

            if(cell==nil)
            {

                cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"reuse"];



                UILabel *lblcomment=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(55,23, 160,20)];
                [lblcomment setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
                [lblcomment setTag:72];
                [lblcomment setTextColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
                [lblcomment setNumberOfLines:0];
                [lblcomment setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15.0]];
                [lblcomment setText:@"Its rude day on goin...Its rude day on goin...Its rude day on goin..."];

                [cell addSubview:lblcomment];
            }
            UILabel *lblcomment=(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:72];



            CGSize contsize={260.00f,3000.00f};
            UIFont *font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:15.0];

            NSString *strt11=@"hellllllooooooooooooooooooo  hellllllooooooooooooooooooo  hellllllooooooooooooooooooo";

            CGSize fontSize=[strt11 sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:contsize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

            float h=20;
            NSLog(@"re %f",fontSize.height);

            if (fontSize.height>22.0f){
                h=fontSize.height+7.0;
                NSLog(@"heigtaaaaa %f",h);
            }

            [lblcomment setFrame:CGRectMake(55,23,260,h)];

            NSString *strDecodeComment=@""hellllllooooooooooooooooooo  hellllllooooooooooooooooooo  hellllllooooooooooooooooooo";




            [lblcomment setText:strDecodeComment];



            [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
            return cell;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. By the way, how do you set the value of `comment_text` ? Is it a variable on your code ?

Comment: Ok. But the equivalent of the `str11` is given **after** the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. That's my problem. I can't update the size of the cell after the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` was called.

Comment: you pass same string in both methods........ now i think your problem will be solve

Comment: It's a dynamic string. The value is on my database. I don't have access to it before. It comes from a mapping with `RestKit` and it's a nested data that I access through `relationships`.

Comment: you get all data from database in a array.....and pass that array in all tableview delegate n datasource method.....  you can get the array value by using that method [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]

Comment: You're right. I've added my code in another solution.